# Cassandra materialized views with mutable partition key

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Does cassandra support creating materialized view with mutable keys?

Does cassandra support the use case of updating partition key while rows are fetched from materialized view via pagination? For the fetched rows, the partition key will be updated to a different value.

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible.  As long as the SSTable files are immutable, the partition keys will be, too.

Comment: Gotcha. So, cassandra doesn't support materialized views with mutable partition key then.